# How to fetch any API using URL by passing some value using form and get response according to form data from api

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, ejs

everyone, I am a beginner in nodejs and expressjs. So while practicing I got a question in my mind is that I am having one URL from where I want to fetch data and I simply did it.
Following is the code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require('request');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
var urlencoderparser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : true });
var data;
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    request.get('http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json', function(err, res, body){
        if(err) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        data = JSON.parse(body);
    });
   res.render('index', {data: data});
   console.log(data);
});
app.listen(3000);
```

And this code is working fine.

Then I thought to change the URL by passing values using form.

[image]

we can enter a value in the form. The value should be either XML or JSON and according to that it will change the URL like the code given below:

```
var url = 'http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format='+form_data
```

Now for this, I tried request.post() in this way:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    Request.post({
    "headers": { "content-type": "application/json" },
    "url": "http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format="+form_data,
    }, (error, response, body) => {
        if(error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        data = JSON.parse(body);
    });
   res.render('index', {data: data});
});
app.listen(3000);
```

But this is not working.
Please help me to know where I am wrong and whether this way is correct for coding in nodejs or expressjs?

Hello everyone i am adding whole code with you for more clearance

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require('request');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var urlencoderparser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : true });

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});

app.post('/', urlencoderparser, function(req, res){
    res.render('form-data', {data : req.body});
    request.post({
    "headers": { "content-type": "application/json" },
    "url": "http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format="+req.body.name,
    }, (error, response, body) => {
        if(error) {
            return console.log(error);
        }
        data = JSON.parse(body);
    });
    console.log(req.body);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: What type of error did you get? For the POST example. Is it in an another file or at the same where GET request? For the first look you require
`var request = require('request');`
but in the GET request you use request with a lowercase and in the POST you use with a camelcase.

Comment: I'm sorry, but is form_data defined anywhere? Shouldn't you use something like req.body.form_data rather than simply form_data?

Comment: @ChiragSharma @wkornilow i am getting this error "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]"

Comment: @mur762 Tried this but giving error.

Comment: @Chirag Sharma Sir, i edited post again and added final code at the last in the post. please look in to that and help me to solve it.

Comment: @wkornilow i edited post again and added final code at the last in the post. please look in to that and help me to solve it

Comment: @mur762 i edited post again and added final code at the last in the post. please look in to that and help me to solve it

Comment: I played a little bit around, I have couple of doubts/issues: 1) are you sure res.render goes before request.post? 2) Are you sure you should use request.post and not request.get? Because I made directly a POST request and the result is the same from the program, while when I made a GET it returned the xml

Comment: @mur762 sir as i am on learning stage, i am not sure of these things. I am just find the exact way to run code in such type of conditions. I just want to enter the value in the form then according to the form value it will call api URL and fetch data and show on other template file

Comment: You need to understand first http requests (https://assertible.com/blog/7-http-methods-every-web-developer-should-know-and-how-to-test-them), but generally speaking, the main two are GET that is used to obtain data and POST to create new data; you're asking for data so you should be using GET